# PHP ftp_connect() returns false

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ftp

```
$ftp_host =  "letsassist.biz";
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; 
$ftp_user_pass = 'mypassword';
$port = 21;
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host,$port );
if($connect_it){
   echo "Connect";
}else{
       echo "Not Connect";
}
```

When i try to run this code in my localhost it echo **"Connect"**,
but when i try to run it remote server (AWS ec2) it echo **"not connect"**.

any solution please.

Comment: check the username and password for remote server.

Comment: "ftp_connect" return false username and password not required to do that

Comment: maybe you need ftp.letsassist.biz, or www.

Comment: The server letsassist.biz, there might be some permissions like the list of allowed ip addresses to establish ftp connection.

Comment: please use `ftp.letsassist.biz`

Comment: Try to SSH into the instance and to telnet TARGET_HOST TARGET_PORT. It checks if the instance is able to reach the target server on that port or not. It can indicate a network settings issue.

Comment: using this "ftp.letsassist.biz" get error php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Comment: Such problems are most likely firewall issues.